# local href's won't mouseover/hover in WAMP

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I run the following code and mouseover the href nothing changes (no highlight, no changed cursor). If I hold click on it, the hover event throws the alert.

I have no clue what could be wrong, this is impacting my web project, but also happening with very basic code.

html:

```
<a href='www.google.com' class='link'>Test</a>
```

css:

```
.link{
    color: #000;
}
a.link:hover{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0afoec1s/)

**Also removing 100% of the jQuery doesn't help either, I was just using that to debug what was going on.**

Comment: What do you expect to happen? It looks normal when copying the code to a jsfiddle. When happens when you click the link?

Comment: It is normal when I through it in jsfiddle or bootply. Clicking it is normal, but hovering never changes the CSS. I'll make a more clear example so people stop troubleshooting javascript.

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/0afoec1s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is rather unclear, I can just guess.

I think your page style is locally set to 'none'.

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-look-wrong-or-appear-differently#w_reset-the-page-style

You may have inadvertently set the page style to No Style. To ensure Firefox is set to use the page's default style:

Press the Alt key to temporarily bring up the traditional Firefox menus, click on the View menu, then select Page Style, then click Basic Page Style.

Now that the page is using its default style, it may be displayed correctly.

(Similiar process for other browsers.)

Comment: This points me in the right direction, it's only happening in Chrome apparently. Firefox / IE work after some testing

Comment: Resetting my settings and reopening the browser did the trick. Thanks

Comment: In chrome it's menu -> tools -> developer tools -> the little gearwheel on the right -> `show user agent styles`

Answer (score 0):

this will fix your problem:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').hover(function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
</script>
```

or you can simply use:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#test').hover(function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: see comment on previous answer. It's not that Javascript that I'm troubleshooting.

Comment: @AndrewWilson WAMP is not the controller of the browser! if this answer doesn't solve your problem, then you must have changed something in your browser's settings, try fixing that

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                     $('#test').hover(function(){
                     alert('test');
                      });
                  });
</script>
```

note: USE JQUERY LIBRARY 1.7.2

AND MAKE IT LIKE THIS

```
<a id="test" href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
```

Comment: neither of these answers worked. the Javascript isn't the problem. it's something about WAMP and hyperlinks I think.

Comment: @Saswat you misunderstood the question. It's not about hover, jquery or alert.